# Is it boxing or unboxing?

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

I often get confused with boxing and unboxing. I mean I understand that both of them mean casting from System.Object to a value type which inherits from it (e.g. System.Int32 or System.Double) or contrariwise. And casting from System.Object to a value type is unboxing, like

```
object o = 12; int i = (int)o;
```

and casting from a value type to System.Object is boxing, like

```
long l = 123L; object o = l;
```

But is it boxing or unboxing in this situation?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void V(object o) => System.Console.WriteLine(o);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 32;
        V(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Boxing occurs. Why is this confusing to you?

Comment: Becaude I had not been sure if it was boxng or unboxing. Thank you.

Comment: @Anonymous: But you have explained it in your own question pretty well: "casting from a value type to System.Object is boxing... casting from System.Object to a value type is unboxing". Here you have an  `int` and the method wants an `Object`, so the `int` gets casted to an `Object`, hence it is boxing (value type to System.Object). You can remember it easily: the value gets boxed into an Object-package

Answer (score 4):

Boxing occurs because you are converting from a value type to a reference type. When you convert to object, you need to package the integer value into an object, so it can be stored on the heap.

[image]

You can use an analyzer like the [ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer#readme-body-tab) to warn you in Visual Studio when boxing occurs in your application.